# hide android app from the app drawer

Tags: android, xml

I've installed an app, after installation, the application will have no icon display yet will run services in the background!

How would I achieve this?

i tried to remove

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

from the androidManifest.xml

Comment: This is not generally possible on Android 3.1+. If you do not have a launcher activity, your app will remain in the stopped state permanently upon installation.

Comment: so it impossible to do so? can't i run it as a service ?

Comment: You can have a service. You *also* need a launcher activity.

Comment: i'm knid of new to android apps development ? the Idea is after running the app it will be hidden

Comment: "i'm knid of new to android apps development ?" -- then perhaps you should spend some time writing apps that do not involve trying to hide from the user who installed the app.

Comment: you are right , i'm tring to build app that is hidden and run using a USSD number ! any way thanks for your helping